# Deleted page still shows and is showing posts archive

Tags: posts, pages

I have a weird issue. I deleted a page and permanently deleted in from the trash but I can still get to it. On the deleted page it shows the posts page ("Blog" page). I have cleared the permalinks, cleared my browser cache and I have looked at it in incognito mode but I can still see the page. Other than turning plugins on and off any other ideas would be appreciated. I am also using a custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to flush the permalinks (press save on the permalinks page)
- Check settings>>reading to see if you have another page used for your "posts page"

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting the old url to your homepage (or another appropriate page on your site).

If you don't know how to setup redirects yourself, you can use a plugin like https://redirection.me/

Also, check to see if the page is still indexed in Google by searching "site:yourdomain.com/yourpage"